# WPF MVVM upload image from computer, to projectfolder, and set build action as Resource

Tags: wpf, mvvm, image-uploading

I can upload an image to my project folder "images" in windows explorer, but not in my project "images" folder. (WHEN running .exe and Visual Studio is closed)

I want to copy an image to my project AND set the "Build Action" to Resource and "Copy to Output" to Copy always.

Why ? 
When my program (.exe) runs (and visual Studio isn't running), I have images shown in the mainWindow. I have a button "upload image". When the user uploads an image, it has to be visible in the mainWindow. The images are shown with binding. AnyBody can help me out?

Mainwindow: (works fine... "Afbeelding" is the name of the image like "abc.jpg")

```
<Button DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource mainViewModelLocator}, Path=MainWindowViewModel}" Command="{Binding AlgorithmActiefCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Content,  ElementName=ollId}" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource ButtonAsImage}">
  <Image Source="{Binding Text, ElementName=image}"  MaxHeight="65" MaxWidth="65" />
</Button>
```

ViewModel: when a uploadImage-button is pressed "LoadImage" function starts:

```
public void LoadImage()
{
//upload image
OpenFileDialog _importAfbeelding = new OpenFileDialog();
_importAfbeelding.Title = "Selecteer een afbeelding";

if (_importAfbeelding.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    var _afbeelding = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_importAfbeelding.FileName));
    ImportPath = _importAfbeelding.FileName;
    string[] _padGesplitst = _importPath.Split('\\');
    ImportNaam = _padGesplitst[(_padGesplitst.Length - 1)];
    string _destinationFullPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    DestinationPath = _destinationFullPath.Remove(_destinationFullPath.Length -10) + "images\\OLL\\"+ ImportNaam;
}
try
{
    File.Copy(ImportPath, this.DestinationPath, true);
    MessageBox.Show("Your images is added with name: " + ImportNaam);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to open file ");
}
}
```

Now I have the image in windows explorer in my "images" map...But nothing is shown in my project. And the name is saved in the database as "Afbeelding" for the binding in MainWindow. But nothing is shown.

MainWindow with images that are already in the images folder. The last is whithout image. That is the one I've added with the upload button.
[image]

This is the upload-image button ("browse")
[image]

Now it is in windows explorer, but not shown with Binding in MainWindow
[image]

Also after restarting the Visual Studio... it will not appear in the project:
[image]

The image is shown with binding and the name is correctly stored in the database
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you

Comment: A build action is just that...a build action.  You can't set the build action of an arbitrary file at run time *after* the application is compiled.

Comment: You want to add the image file to your project in Visual Studio? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/05/21/visual-studio-tip-8-adding-existing-files-with-show-all-files/

Comment: Paul Abbott, Yes that makes sense.
Kirodge, Yes that's what I try, but not when I am in Visual Studio! When the exe runs, whithout Visual Studio opened

Comment: Note that setting both *Build Action* to *Resource* and *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy always* doesn't make sense anyway. The former is meant to make the image file an assembly resource (so that ist is accessible by a Resource File Pack URI), while the purpose of the latter is just to copy the image file to the build target directory, i.e. the directory where the executable is written (to load it from a defined relative file path). This is something you could easily do during runtime of your application.

Comment: However, it might be better to load images from a dedicated image folder somewhere in the file system, i.e. under `C:\ProgramData\<YourApp>\Images`, and copy new image files there.

Comment: @Clements: We don't have really installed the program. It's highschool project. We use the exe in bin/debug folder. So I checked the C:\ProgramData but there is no folder with my application. I assume that you  mean like the picture above ? my application in "AlgorithmTrainer" and I store the pictures under that "images" folder

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution that I want to share.
First I've changed location where I upload the image. I upload it now in the debug folder:
[image]

Then I copy the image to that folder:
[image]

Then it was difficult to show the image.
First I defined the path in ViewModel:
[image]

Then build the correct string for your image source (path+imagename):
[image]

Finally it worked! I hope it helps others who want to upload and use the image in a running program.